# How to get correct date time format after upgrading full calendar API

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I have upgraded full calendar from version 1.6.4 to version 2.0.0 and i have also integrated Google Calendar in it. During upgradation, I have replaced fullcalendar.min.js, jquery-ui.custom.min.js, moment.js and fullcalendar.js.

After that i noticed that **format of date** has been changed. for example.

**First issue in date format**

Previously  Start/End value in eventSources = Sun Feb 15 2015 08:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time).

Now Start/end value = 2015-09-25

**Second issue in date format**

**In eventClick:** function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) { } function, value of jsEvent is also not same.

I tried to play with timezone but it was unsuccessful.

If i upgrade to full calendar latest version 2.2.7 then Google calendar integration does not work.

**Main problem:** date format changed with upgradation of full-calendar. I have not specified any time zone. It might be other problem but i did not able to figure out it.

Comment: I would recommend you to use momentJS. It helps with the time issues a lot. In combination with that try to set the timezone to `local`.

Comment: Fullcalendar 2.0+ uses `moment()` objects as dates. Documentation: http://momentjs.com/docs/ . Also, you will need to actually ask a question if you want it answered. Currently you've just told us that x changed. Questions look like `How do I get the date from eventClick?` or `This code is giving error x, how do I fix it?`.